# Problem when copying image from project resources to documents folder in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsfilemanager

I'm having a problem copying an image from the project resources to the Documents folder.

I'm using NSFileManager's copyItemAtPath. When I test it on the simulator it works fine, but when I do it on the device (iPod or iPad) the image is copied with errors.

Using PhoneView I can see the copied image but when I open it, the image is empty. When I open it on Firefox the next message is shown:

The image “file:///../logo.png” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *logoPath = [webPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logo"];

if (![fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:logoPath]) {
   NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo" ofType:@"png"];
   NSError *error = nil;
   BOOL isSuccess = [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:logoPath error:&      
   if (!isSuccess || error) {
      if (error)
         NSLog(@"ERROR copy logo: %@", [error description]);
      }
   }
```

}

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would like to thank you all for your answers, all of them helped to resolve my issue.

I'm not sure why, but when I copy a PNG image, somehow the image was corrupted, when I tried doing the same thing with a JPG image the problem was solved.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

i cant find any error in your code , i can only give one suggestion

convert your image into NSData 
and write to document folder

NSData *data;//data from you logo image

```
[data writeToFile:<document path> atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure but I think your line:

```
NSString *logoPath = [webPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logo"];
```

should be:

```
NSString *logoPath = [webPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logo.png"];
```

I think iOs does not recognize "logo" as "logo.png".

Comment: It is, in order to make the code comprehensible, I renamed that part, and forgot of the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at upperCase character in file name, sometimes errors come from that, iPhone is case sensitives, mac-simulator probably is not...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a problem with the file format. When I changed the image to a JPG, the problem was gone. It seems that apple changes PNG images, I'm not really sure about this, but for what I've experienced, it makes sence.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@mikywan has correctly pointed out that the JPG works perfect but the PNG images when copied from the resource bundle are corrupted.

If someone still wants to use the png images here is a solution, select the build settings on your target and set the "Compress PNG Files" to "NO". The the PNGs inside the resources are not will not be changed while building the app.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question, but it looks like Apple still suck so the problem is still there 2 years later. In case someone else comes across the problem, this is how I solved it, which is basically spelling out what @Rajesh already said:

```
BOOL success = [UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"]) 
                   writeToFile:logoPath atomically:YES];
```